# Easiest way to derive subset array of highest 10 values?

Tags: javascript

In javascript I have an array as follows:

```
var foo = [2, 2, 4, 4, 128, 2, 2, 1, 4, 18, 27, 16, 2, 1, 18, 21, 5, 1, 128, 1, 2, 2, 1, 18, 12, 60, 2, 28, 1, 17, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 27, 2, 17, 7, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 7, 2, 7, 6, 1, 7, 1, 5, 8, 4];
```

And I am interested in finding a way (within one loop, not multiple) to derive a subset array of the highest 10 values, where the previous position of the value is the 'key' (so simulating a Map object):

eg:

```
var fooTopTen = [[4, 128], [18, 128], [25, 60], [27, 28], [10, 27], [37, 27], [15, 21], [9, 18], [14, 18], [23, 18]];
```

Comment: If you have two equal values which is considered the greater one? Is it the first one in the array foo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer used a reverse index table, but contained some bugs - which are now fixed - and was harder to understand than the following code.

This is actually the slowest of all solutions given in the answers - for maximum performance, check my other answer.

```
var foo = [2, 2, 4, 4, 128, 2, 2, 1, 4, 18, 27, 16, 2, 1, 18, 21, 5, 1, 128, 1, 2, 2, 1, 18, 12, 60, 2, 28, 1, 17, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 27, 2, 17, 7, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 7, 2, 7, 6, 1, 7, 1, 5, 8, 4];

var fooTopTen = [];

// add index to values
for(var i = 0, len = foo.length; i < len; ++i)
    fooTopTen.push([i, foo[i]]);

// sort first by value (descending order), then by index (ascending order)
fooTopTen.sort(function(t1, t2) {
    return t2[1] - t1[1] || t1[0] - t2[0];
});

// shorten array to correct size
fooTopTen.length = 10;

// output top ten to check result
document.writeln('[[' + fooTopTen.join('], [') + ']]');
```

The second part of the comparison function (the one comparing the indices) is not needed, as `sort()` is stable in most implementations (this isn't required by ECMA [according to MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Sort)). I'll leave it in as an example to how sorting with multiple requirements can be done...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the de-bugged version of my previous answer using an index table. I did a little benchmarking and for the input given in the question, this solition will be faster than anything else which has been suggested in this thread till now:

```
var foo = [2, 2, 4, 4, 128, 2, 2, 1, 4, 18, 27, 16, 2, 1, 18, 21, 5, 1, 128, 1, 2, 2, 1, 18, 12, 60, 2, 28, 1, 17, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 27, 2, 17, 7, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 7, 2, 7, 6, 1, 7, 1, 5, 8, 4];

var indexTable = {}, uniqueValues = [];

// --- build reverse index table, find unique values

for(var i = foo.length; i--; ) {
    var value = foo[i];
    if(indexTable.hasOwnProperty(value))
        indexTable[value].push(i);
    else {
        indexTable[value] = [i];
        uniqueValues.push(value);
    }
}

// --- sort unique values in ascending order

uniqueValues.sort(function(i1, i2) {
    return i1 - i2;
});

// --- find ten greatest values

var fooTopTen = [], k = 0;

for(var i = uniqueValues.length; k < 10 && i--; ) {
    var value = uniqueValues[i],
        indices = indexTable[value];

    for(var j = indices.length; k < 10 && j--; )
        fooTopTen[k++] = [indices[j], value];
}

// --- output result

document.writeln('[[' + fooTopTen.join('], [') + ']]');
```

Answer (score 1):

This runs once through the main array it searches, inserting items at the appropriate place in the results array:

```
function top10(arr) {
  var results = [[0,Number.MAX_VALUE],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]];

  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    // search from back to front
    for (var j=9; j>=0; j--) {
       if (arr[i] <= results[j][1]) {
         if (j==9)
           break;
         results.splice(j+1, 0, [i, arr[i]]);
         results.pop();
         break;
      }
    }
  }
  return results.slice(1);
}
```

For large arrays this should even be rather fast, since most times the inner loop should only do one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = [2, 2, 4, 4, 128, 2, 2, 1, 4, 18, 27, 16, 2, 1, 18, 21, 5, 1, 128, 1, 2, 2, 1, 18, 12, 60, 2, 28, 1, 17, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 27, 2, 17, 7, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 7, 2, 7, 6, 1, 7, 1, 5, 8, 4];

var index = 0;
var result = foo.map( function(a){ return [index++, a]; } )
         .sort( function(a,b){ return (a[1] < b[1]); } )
         .splice( 0, 10 );

document.write(result.join( '  ' ));
```

If foo is very large compared to the size of result required, it may be quicker to iterate over foo insertion-sorting each element into result as we come across it.

Comment: Thanks v much for your submission, didn't realise that two people were going to answer. Yours is very concise and short, shame I can't choose two suitable answers

Comment: We're even using the same algorithm; my low-level approach will additionally work out of the box with ie, though...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sorting method
function sortNumber(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

// Find the offset of an element in array
function findOffset(element, array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == element) {
            // Make sure we don't find it again
            array[i] = null;
            return i;
        }
    }
}

var foo = [2, 2, 4, 4, 128, 2, 2, 1, 4, 18, 27, 16, 2, 1, 18, 21, 5, 1, 128, 1, 2, 2, 1, 18, 12, 60, 2, 28, 1, 17, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 27, 2, 17, 7, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 7, 2, 7, 6, 1, 7, 1, 5, 8, 4];
// Copies
var bar = foo.slice();
var baz = foo.slice();
var fooTopTen = new Array(10);
// Sort
bar.sort(sortNumber).reverse();
// Create the results
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fooTopTen[i] = new Array(2);
    fooTopTen[i][0] = findOffset(bar[i], baz);
    fooTopTen[i][1] = bar[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

computer-science-y answer:

problem statement: Given a large array X of length N, and a small number m < N (here m=10), produce an array Y of length m where each element of Y contains the pair {i,X[i]} such that the set of X{i} are the m largest elements of X.

If m is much smaller than N, then loop over elements of X and sort them into Y, discarding pairs to maintain at most m elements. (i.e. as moonshadow mentioned)

Sorting X will cost you O(N log N) elements. Iterating over X and sorting into Y should cost you only O(N log m) elements.

Comment: What is the time-complexity of the index-table approach? Building the index table should be linear in the input size, sorting the unique values should be `N log N` (N: number of unique elements) on average (assuming quicksort) and building the result array is linear in the number of requested values

Comment: that sounds like N log N dominates (the others are O(N) which is smaller).